# Show that there is an isomorphism $H_n(X, \{a\}) \cong H_n(X,A),$ for all $n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A$ be a subspace of $X$. Let $a \in A$. Assume that $H_n(A, \{a\}) = 0$ for all $n$. Show that there is an isomorphism $$H_n(X, \{a\}) \cong H_n(X,A),$$ for all $n$.

We have the following exact sequences $$\dots \longrightarrow H_n(A) \overset{i_\ast}{\longrightarrow} H_n(X) \overset{j_\ast}{\longrightarrow} H_n(X,A) \overset{\partial}{\longrightarrow} H_{n-1}(A) \longrightarrow \dots$$

$$\dots \longrightarrow H_n(\{a\}) \overset{i'_\ast}{\longrightarrow} H_n(X) \overset{j_\ast}{\longrightarrow} H_n(X,\{a\}) \overset{\partial'}{\longrightarrow} H_{n-1}(\{a\}) \longrightarrow \dots$$
and
$$\dots \longrightarrow H_n(\{a\}) \overset{i''_\ast}{\longrightarrow} H_n(A) \overset{j''_\ast}{\longrightarrow} H_n(A,\{a\}) \overset{\partial''}{\longrightarrow} H_{n-1}(\{a\}) \longrightarrow \dots$$

From the last one I can derive that since $H_n(A, \{a\}) = 0$ and the sequence is exact one gets $$H_n(A)=\ker(j''_\ast) = \text{Im}(i''_\ast)$$ which implies that $i''_\ast$ is surjective.

I don't quite see how I can find a map from $H_n(X, \{a\}) \to H_n(X,A)$. One consideration would be if I had some chain maps between these sequences (complexes?) to use that to determine whether it's a bijection, but I have no idea on how to construct such a map. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a triple $(X, A, B)$ with $B \subset A \subset X$, there is a long exact sequence

$$\dots \to H_{n+1}(X, A) \to H_n(A, B) \to H_n(X, B) \to H_n(X, A) \to H_{n-1}(A, B) \to \dots$$

See page $118$ of [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) by Hatcher for example. Taking $B = \{a\}$, this immediately yields the desired isomorphisms.

We can also rewrite this long exact sequence when $B = \{a\}$ because $H^n(X, \{a\}) \cong \widetilde{H}_n(X)$ and $H_n(A, \{a\}) \cong \widetilde{H}_n(A)$:

$$\dots \to H_{n+1}(X, A) \to \widetilde{H}_n(A) \to \widetilde{H}_n(X) \to H_n(X, A) \to \widetilde{H}_{n-1}(A) \to \dots$$

From this point of view, the hypothesis $H_n(A, \{a\}) = 0$ translates to $\widetilde{H}_n(A) = 0$, so $H_n(X, A) \cong \widetilde{H}_n(X)$, which in turn is isomorphic to $H_n(X,\{a\})$.

Comment: From the link if we use this exact sequence, then $H_n(A, \{a\}) = 0$ implies that $\ker(j_\ast) = \text{Im}(i_\ast)= 0$ and so $j_\ast$ is injective, but does it give surjectivity?

Comment: @Divider: I'm not sure what you mean by $i_*$ and $j_*$ for the long exact sequence I wrote.

Comment: I would write it as $$\dots \to H_{n+1}(X, A) \to H_n(A, B) \overset{i_\ast}{\to} H_n(X, B) \overset{j_\ast}{\to} H_n(X, A) \overset{\partial}{\to} H_{n-1}(A, B) \to \dots$$ and we're interested in showing that $j_\ast$ is an isomorphism. @michael-albanese

Comment: Well $H_n(A, B) = H_n(A, \{a\}) = 0$, so $i_*$ is the zero map, therefore $\ker j_* = \operatorname{im}i_* = 0$, so $j_*$ is injective. We also have $H_{n-1}(A, B) = H_{n-1}(A, \{a\}) = 0$, so $\partial$ is the zero map, so $\operatorname{im}j_* = \ker\partial = H_n(X,A)$, i.e. $j_*$ is surjective. In general, if you have an exact sequence with $\dots\to 0\to G \xrightarrow{\varphi} H \to 0 \to \dots$, then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.